# Understanding how passing arguments to the decorated function works

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm learning about Python decorators and I have some difficulties understanding how passing arguments to the decorated function works. I'm **not** talking about passing arguments to the decorator itself but of the case where the original function takes additional arguments. For instance, I'm trying to understand the following simple example (credits for the code snippet goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/5507389) answer):

```
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        print("I got args! Look: {0}, {1}".format(arg1, arg2))
        fn(arg1, arg2)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def print_full_name(first_name, last_name):
    print("My name is {0} {1}".format(first_name, last_name))

print_full_name("John", "Doe")
# outputs:
# I got args! Look: John Doe
# My name is John Doe
```

So, if I intentionally break the code by removing the arguments `arg1` and `arg2` of the wrapper, I get the following error: `TypeError: wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`. It's strange to me that the wrapper is expecting 2 arguments when it's defined without any arguments inside the parentheses. Also, is it unclear to me **how** the `first_name` and `last_name` argument values are "mapped" to the arguments of the wrapper function. We only pass those arguments to the `print_full_name` function but it seems they also get passed to the `wrapper` function. Maybe this has to do with the order in which things are run but this is not clear for me.

I know they are a lot of great answers here regarding this topic but I could not find one that clearly explains this specific part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break down the calls that happen.

So, you have:

```py
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        print("I got args! Look: {0}, {1}".format(arg1, arg2))
        fn(arg1, arg2)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def print_full_name(first_name, last_name):
    print("My name is {0} {1}".format(first_name, last_name))

print_full_name("John", "Doe")
# outputs:
# I got args! Look: John Doe
# My name is John Doe
```

Because you have decorated the `print_full_name` with the `decorator`, then when you do

```py
print_full_name("John", "Doe")
```

first the decorator `decorator` is called with argument `print_full_name`, as in:

```py
decorator(print_full_name)("John", "Doe")
```

The `decorator(print_full_name)` is defined as

```py
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(...):
        ...
        ...
    return wrapper
```

and returns the `wrapper`. Thus, the above turns out to be:

```py
wrapper("John", "Doe")
```

Then, because the `wrapper` is defined as

```py
def wrapper(arg1, arg2)
```

in the body of the `wrapper` you have that `arg1="John"` and `arg2="Doe"`.

Finally, because the `wrapper` is defined inside the `decorator`, it knows what the `fn` is, where `fn=print_full_name`.

And that is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In short: passing arguments is *exactly* the same; you just need to be aware of *which* function you are actually calling.

---

Decorator syntax is just function application in disguise. Without it, you would just write

```
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        print("I got args! Look: {0}, {1}".format(arg1, arg2))
        fn(arg1, arg2)
    return wrapper


def print_full_name(first_name, last_name):
    print("My name is {0} {1}".format(first_name, last_name))

print_full_name = decorator(print_full_name)
```

So now, `print_full_name` does not refer to the original function that prints the sentence. It refers to the function returned by `decorator`. The original function is not lost; the new function is a closure over the name `fn`, which is a reference to the original function.